# Search bar in modal-body for auto search based on text entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">{{selectedClassName}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body errorDetailPannel">
                <table class="table table-sm table-inverse table-responsive table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Line</th>
                            <th>Review Feedback</th>
                        </tr>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control search-box" placeholder="Search">
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="eachClass in selectedClassErrDetails">
                            <td>{{eachClass.lineNumber}}</td>
                            <td>{{eachClass.reviewFeedback}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

 </div>
```

The JS File:

```
function OrderFormController($scope,$http){

    var urlString = window.location.href;
    var urlParams = parseURLParams(urlString);

    var date = urlParams['date'];

    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "**********************************************,
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    var parsed = JSON.parse(jsonData);
    $scope.selectedClassErrDetails = [];
    $scope.selectedClassName = "";
    $scope.showErrorDetails = function(classNameKey){
        $scope.selectedClassName = classNameKey;
        $scope.selectedClassErrDetails = $scope.sampleJSON[classNameKey];
        angular.element('#myModal').modal('show');
    };

    $scope.sampleJSON = parsed;

};

function parseURLParams(url) {
    var queryStart = url.indexOf("?") + 1,
        queryEnd   = url.indexOf("#") + 1 || url.length + 1,
        query = url.slice(queryStart, queryEnd - 1),
        pairs = query.replace(/\+/g, " ").split("&"),
        parms = {}, i, n, v, nv;

    if (query === url || query === "") return;

    for (i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        nv = pairs[i].split("=", 2);
        n = decodeURIComponent(nv[0]);
        v = decodeURIComponent(nv[1]);

        if (!parms.hasOwnProperty(n)) parms[n] = [];
        parms[n].push(nv.length === 2 ? v : null);
    }
    return parms;
}
```

I have introduced an search panel at the top of my modal, but it does not work. I dont need a submit button, but when a text is entered in the search box it should filter the result of the moday-content based on the matching phrase in the search box. In the image below I gave asd but it did not filter the result.

[image]

**Modifed JS:**

```
function searchFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("searchBar");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("errorTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
        if (td) {
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where's your JS?

Comment: Given the JS, but the JS only gets data from my rest call, nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>My Customers</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

do you want to search like this?

Comment: Yes, I have modified the JS according to my table ID, but somehow it does not show anything. Added modified JS above, and have added `onkeyup="searchFunction()`

Comment: No problem, got it. my table data is on index 1.